# How to add a colorbar to a Matplotlib subfigure (not a subplot)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to add a colorbar to a subfigure? I try the following but get an error.

Here's sample code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.random.randint(-2,5,10) for x in range(0,5)])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(2,1, wspace=0.1)

axsTop = subfigs[0].subplots(1,1)
axsBot = subfigs[1].subplots(1,4)
axsTop.imshow(a)
subfigs[0].colorbar(a)
# subfigs[0].colorbar(a, ax=axsTop) # tried this, too
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_array'

Answer (score 0):

In case it might help others, I found a solution using a [nested gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_nested.html) rather than subfigures. The colorbar is connected to its own subplot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.colorbar import Colorbar
import sys

a = np.array([np.random.randint(-2,5,10) for x in range(0,5)])

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(
                    ncols=3,
                    nrows=3,
                    figure=fig,
                    height_ratios=[1,1,1],
                    width_ratios=[1,0.05,1])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
plt1 = ax1.imshow(a)

cbax = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
cb = Colorbar(ax=cbax, mappable=plt1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])
x_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
y_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
ax2.scatter(x_vals, y_vals)

ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1,2])
x_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
y_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
ax3.scatter(x_vals, y_vals)

ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[2,0])
x_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
y_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
ax4.scatter(x_vals, y_vals)

ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[2,2])
x_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
y_vals = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
ax5.scatter(x_vals, y_vals)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[Sample output image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh3Ye.png)